# Working with the characters backslash and curly brackets in regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex, backslash, curly-brackets

I am using regular expressions to recognize the lines containing `\begin{frame}` in `.tex` files. Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re,sys

def isEven(num):
    res = [False,True][bool(num % 2 == 0)]
    return res

textin = open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()
nline = 0
pat = r'\b\begin{frame}\b'
for line in textin:
    line = line.strip(' ')
    #print 'Test: ',line[:13]
    if re.match(pat,line):
        print 'here'
        nline += 1
    if isEven(nline):
        print '%',line.strip('\n')
    else:
        print line.strip('\n')
```

This program aims to add the character '%' before the lines in the tex file if the number of frames is even. In other words, I want to comment the slides which the slide number is even. 
Do you know what is the wrong in the pattern?

Comment: There are no word boundaries between a backslash and probably a whitespace character nor between a curly bracket and a whitespace character. so you need to remove them. When you want to write a literal backslash in a pattern you need to escape it (with an other backslash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your pattern string again:

```
r'\b\begin{frame}\b'
```

Notice it starts with '\b\b'.  You mean the first one as a word boundary, the second one as part of what you want to match -- but how could `re` possibly guess what you mean each for?!

I don't think you need the word-boundaries, by the way -- in fact they may mess up the matching.  Moreover, `re.match` only matches at the start; since you say "contain", as opposed to "start with", in your Q's text, you may actually want `re.search`.

To match a backslash, you need to double it in the pattern.  And you can use a single backslash to escape punctuation, such as those braces.

So I would recommend...:

```
def isEven(n): return n%2 == 0

nline = 0
pat = r'\\begin\{frame\}'
with open(sys.argv[1]) as textin:
    for line in textin:
        line = line.strip()
        if re.search(pat,line):
            print 'here'
            nline += 1
        if isEven(nline):
            print '%', line
        else:
            print line
```

I've done a few more improvements but they're not directly relevant to your Q (e.g, use `with` to open the file, and loop on it line by line; strip each line of whitespace completely, once, rather than by instalments; etc -- but you don't **have** to use any of these:-).